# Selecting <p> within a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select the second `<p>` tag and style it within a `itemize` class div. Here is the example HTML:

```
<div class="itemize">
    <p> Order Summery</p>
    <div>
        <p><strong>Packages:</strong> </p> <!-- i want to select this P tag-->
        <p><strong>Date:</strong> </p>
        <p><strong>Style:</strong> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to  select and style the first `<p>` which is immediately after the second `<div>`. The second `<p>` has no ID or class.

How can I select it via jQuery?

Comment: thanks this works but i have an other issue now.. :S. basicall the structure is the same but js file include another P before it select some thing then its change to <p><strong> Packages</strong></p>. how can i do that. like first p coming from js `<p>select your order</p>` when i select some thing it changes via jquery to `<p><strong>Packages:</strong> </p> <!-- i want to select this P tag-->`. how can i add class to the second appeared P

Comment: In future, please spend more time writing or formatting your post. Formatting help can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
$('.itemize > div > p:eq(0)')
```

`.itemize > div` goes till:

```
<div class="itemize">
    <p> Order Summery</p>
</div>
```

And

`.itemize > div > p:eq(0)`

```
<div class="itemize">
    <p> Order Summery</p>
    <div>
        <p><strong>Packages:</strong> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `>` allows to target direct children whereas `eq(index)` is used to get first `p` that you want.

Answer (score 15):

```
$('.itemize div p:first').html()
```

Check this link: [http://jsfiddle.net/QJTYx/](http://jsfiddle.net/QJTYx/1/)

If you want to add class to that p tag:

```
$('.itemize div p:first').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: Links are not answers. At least copypasta your line of JS in the answer as well. Taken from [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116304/186879): `Link-only answers can be actively harmful if links break. And they do break, even on sites that are seemingly going to be around forever.`. Thanks for the update. `:)`

Comment: thanks this works but i have an other issue now.. :S. basicall the structure is the same but js file include another P before it  select some thing then its change to `<p><strong> Packages</strong></p>`. how can i do that. like first p coming from js <p>select your order</p> when i select some thing it changes via jquery to `<p><strong>Packages:</strong> </p> <!-- i want to select this P tag-->`.

Comment: Do you just want to add class to first p tag?? If yes then i have updated code here. http://jsfiddle.net/QJTYx/4/

Answer (score 6):

```
var test = $('.itemize')​.find('div:first')​.find(​'p:first')​​​.html();
alert(test);
​
```

Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/H8vwA/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.itemize>div>p:first').addClass('someClass');
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
$('.itemize div p').first().addClass('hello');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this..

```
$(".itemize div p:first").text();
```

hope it will works..

Answer (score 1):

`$('.itemize>div>p').first().css(styles go here)` most of the ones above work as well

jQuery selectors work a bit like css selectors, check out this [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery) to get more info.